# Excel connection string to OneDrive file

Tags: excel, connection, connection-string, dsn

I have an Excel workbook that serves as a template that pulls data from another Excel file.  When the Excel files were created they resided in a network shared drive and all the connections strings pointed to the location in the drive.  Now we have moved those files to OneDrive and the connection strings no longer work.

When I open the connection I select to connect from **Network**... -> **Connect to a Web site that you can use to store your documents and pictures.** ->  **Choose a custom network location.**

There I enter the link in OneDrive to the Excel file that serves as data source like https://myCompany.my.sharepoint/personal/my_company_com/Documents/sourceFolder/myFile.xls but I get an error message saying that the folder location is unknown.

I also tried to change the properties manually to my synched shared files in file explorer like

```
DNS=Excel
Files;
DBQ=C:\Users\myUserName\myOneDrive\sourceFolder\myFile.xls;
Dir=C:\Users\myUserName\myOneDrive\sourceFolder;
DriverId=1046;
MaxBufferSize=2048;PageTimeout=5;
```

But that brings up the problem that my username is hardcoded and would work only for me requiring to change the username for each user.  I haven't been able to find a way to replace the username for a variable like `%username%` since that is not recognized by the data connection or to connect directly to the OneDrive location like

`https://myCompany.my.sharepoint/personal/my_company_com/Documents/sourceFolder/myFile.xls.`

How do I connect to a data connection in OneDrive.

Comment: What Excel version are you using. Could you use Power Query?

Comment: Hi @Ricardo Diaz.  We are using Microsoft Excel for Microsoft 365.  Version 2015.

Comment: HI Ricardo, I figured out what was breaking the template.  Under Queries & Connections I deleted all the connections that were there right after I connected from Web and then did a Load & Transform data.  Thank you for your help.  Very much appreciated.

Comment: Sure. Remember you can create a named range and use it as a variable inside Power Query